# Wrong url in the link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

When I use link_to in rails

I know that the form is

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)
# => <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>
```

but in my code

```
<% @posts.each do |post|%>
  <h2><%=post.title %></h2>
  <p><%= post.content%></p>
  <%=link_to "show", posts_path(post.id) %>
<%end%>
```

I expect my url looks like `posts/1`
but it was `posts.1`

Comment: may you try `<%=link_to "show", posts_path(post) %>`

Comment: sorry it doesn't work :-(

Comment: can you share your routes.rb file , you need to add post_path(post) in your html file

Answer (score 1):

link_to comes with syntax/signature `link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)`
Which creates a link tag of the given name using a URL created by the set of options.

Signatures;

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
  # url is a String; you can use URL helpers like
  # posts_path

link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
  # url_options, except :method, is passed to url_for

link_to(options = {}, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end

link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

I will take the same example from your question,

This `link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)`
creates path;

```
# => <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>
```

whereas, `<%=link_to "show", posts_path(post.id) %>` creates

```
# => <a href="/profiles.1">show</a>
```

Other options to create appropriate routes are as follows;

```
link_to "Profile", @profile
# => <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>

link_to "Profile", controller: "profiles", action: "show", id: @profile
# => <a href="/profiles/show/1">Profile</a>
```

Hope this could help you otherwise see this [link_to apidoc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%=link_to "show", post_path(post) %>`

`post` not `posts`. See here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: That's would be good if you can describe the problem and your answer, to gather more upvotes.